# How old is my Toshiba Satellite Pro?

Tags: toshiba-laptop

I can't figure out how old my laptop is.

The model is a *Toshiba Satellite Pro C850 - 1HE* and  PART  No. *PSCBXE - 01Q00EEN*.

I've tried searching but haven't been able to find anything. How old is it? The year will do although month would be better if possible.

Here's a photo of the label on the underside of the computer:

[image]

Comment: Check it yourself http://support.toshiba.com/warranty

Comment: Just a note, the part # you provided seems to be inaccurate.

Comment: I've tried that. The part number is correct; q updated with image of the underside of my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your laptop is **3 years, 10 months, 25 days** old as of today.

Purchase data is Jun 26, 2013

[image: screenshot from lenovo warranty check page]

Couldn't find it using Part no. but Serial Number revealed it